# erro no rake:db setup (falha ao conectar-se com o postgreSQL) no subsistema Ubuntu para Windows

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, psql, postgresql-10

Olá! Estou usando o subsistema Ubuntu (18.04) no windows com *ruby on rails* (*ruby* versão 2.5.1 e *rails* 5.2.2) e com *PostgreSQL* na versão 10. Rodei um `rake db:setup` na raiz do meu projeto Rails e retornou o seguinte erro:

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>           Is the server running locally and accepting
>           connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"? Couldn't create
>   'db/devpostgresql' database. Please check your configuration. rake
>   aborted!

segui esse tutorial para instalar e configurar o subsistema Ubuntu no Windows juntamente com ruby on rails e postgreSQL:

https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10#git

o postgreSQL foi instalado no windows pois assim é recomendado

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link: https://medium.com/@stephanedmonson/solution-for-connecting-postgresql-via-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux-ubuntu18-c79940fa5742 E eu creio que seria melhor vc rodar o postgres no windows, se possível.